# Error with JSF2 and RichFaces

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, jsf-2

I'm trying to use RichFaces on a working JSF2 application. I incorporated the RichFaces jars, changed the web.xml but got the following error:

```
17:49:13,097 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] Error Rendering View[/login.xhtml]: java.lang.NullPointerExcept
ion
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:936)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.CompositeComponentTagHandler.createComponent(CompositeComponentTagHandler.java:154)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.createComponent(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:311)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:145)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:114)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:91)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:204)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:114)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:91)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:86)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:91)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:75)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:301)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:360)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:339)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:191)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:149)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:86)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:75)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:145)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:716)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:351)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:126)
        at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
        at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:127)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:336)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:479)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:407)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.forwardToLoginPage(FormAuthenticator.java:318)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:559)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:95)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:872)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

It seems that some jars are missing, but I cannot seem to find this cause. The above error is the only thing that the log spits out.

Here's web.xml:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-validator-tags/general.taglib.xml;
                        /WEB-INF/faces-converter-tags/general.converter.taglib.xml
           </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!--
        Startup Servlet <servlet> <servlet-name>StartUpServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>pt.cgd.agile.util.StartupServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> </servlet>
    -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DISABLE_FACELET_JSF_VIEWHANDLER</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
        <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Making the RichFaces skin spread to standard HTML controls -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING</param-name>
        <param-value>enable</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
        <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING</param-name>
        <param-value>enable</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>
        <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!--
        Just here so the JSF implementation can initialize, *not* used at
        runtime
    -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Just here so the JSF implementation can initialize -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.jsf</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/loginError.jsf</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/errors/error.jsf</location>
    </error-page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We moved on to another component lib. We were deploying to WAS, so it was a headache anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the issue you were having is because RichFaces 3.3.x isn't fully compatible with JSF2.  Specifically the composite component feature of facelets won't work.  It appears that is what your issue was